# Bundling and not bundling in production and test environments in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, debugging, bundling-and-minification

I am using the ASP.NET Bundling mechanism:

```
            BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Master-js").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.form.js",
                       "~/Scripts/jquery.MetaData.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.viewport.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"
                     ));
```

I want this to happen if the build is in release. If the build is in debug, I want the un-minified individual files to load so debugging would be easy.

The only way I have been able to do this is to write the following in my view:

```
    <%  if(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
        {
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Scripts/respond.min.js'></script>");
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Scripts/jquery.form.js'></script>");
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Scripts/jquery.MetaData.js'></script>");
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js'></script>");
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Scripts/bootstrap.js'></script>");
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Scripts/jquery.viewport.js'></script>");
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' src='../../Scripts/jquery.cookie.js'></script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Master-js");
        }
%>
```

As you can see, I am repeating myself here. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you run the site in debug mode and use `Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Master-js");` on your view, it should have the non-minified version served with separate script tags for each.

Comment: @StevenV, if you add your comment as a anser, I will mark it as correct. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

By default, when using `Scripts.Render()` on your view and if the application has debugging enabled (`debug="true"` in the web.config) the files will not be bundled or minified. Also a individual script tag will be rendered for every asset in that bundle.

You can manually enable/disable bundling and minification by using [`System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundletable.enableoptimizations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)